# Two people buying gingerbread and gluehwein in an efficient way

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction

Bud and Terence visit a Christmas Market.
Bud checks his money and notes that he could buy 8 gingerbread and 1 gluehwein and is left with 70 ct and cannot buy anything further.
Terence checks his money and states that he can also do it in a way that 70 ct are left, but prefers to take 5 gingerbread and 2 gluehwein and 40 ct are left.
If Bud and Terence put their money together, they can take 9 gingerbread and 4 gluehwein and are left with 50 ct.

What is the price for one gingerbread and for one gluehwein?

Comment: By "Terence... can do it in a way that 70¢ are left", do you mean that Terence can buy exactly the same thing as Bud with 70¢ left?  Or that Terence can buy *some* combination of things such that he has 70¢ left?

Comment: (I'm pretty sure that it's the latter, since you get a non-sensical answer if you assume the former, but I wanted to be sure)

Comment: correct, Terence can buy some combination of things such that he has 70¢ left.

Comment: I have to ask, since you're a high-rep user here who must be aware of [site policies/scope](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2784/5373). Is this question really a maths *puzzle*, or a cookie-cutter (pun intended) maths *problem*?

Comment: Well, I thought this is more a math puzzle than a math problem, but if I'm wrong, I'm fine to close/remove this question.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I can say that it's at least a well designed question. I can only see this after solving it, but maybe there is a smarter way to do it, which would definitely make it a *puzzle*. Besides, it's about the time to talk about gingerbread and gluehwein.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $A=$gingerbread and $B=$gluehwein.
Let $X=$money of Bud and $Y=$money of Terence.
All in cents.

The conditions are:

> - $8A + B + 70 = X$
>
>  - $A, B > 70$, and also $A, B \in \Bbb Z$
>
>  - $5A + 2B + 40 = Y$
>
>  - $9A + 4B + 50 = X + Y$
>
>  - $\exists u, v \in \Bbb Z_{\geq 0}, uA + vB + 70 = Y$

From the three identities, we get

> - $B = 4A + 60$
>
>  - $X = 12A + 130$
>
>  - $Y = 13A + 160$

Now consider the possibilities of $u, v$.

**Case $v = 0$**:

> $(u - 13)A = 90$
>
>  Since $A > 70$, we must have $u = 14$, which leads to $A = 90, B = 420$.

**Case $v = 1$**:

> $(u - 9)A = 30$
>
>  This has no solution with $A > 70$.

**Case $v = 2$**:

> $(5 - u)A = 30$
>
>  This has no solution with $A > 70$.

**Case $v = 3$**:

> $(1 - u)A = 90$
>
>  Since $A > 70$, we must have $u = 0$, which leads to $A = 90, B = 420$.

**Case $v \geq 4$**:

> $(u + 4v - 13)A + (60v - 90) = 0$
>
>  This only has solutions with negative $A$.

---

Thus the answer is

> gingerbread $0.9$ euro, gluehwein $4.2$ euros.

Comment: very well solved!